# Remove all except the chinese characters with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is a sentence, written in chinese.

This contains chinese characters, and other filler things, like spaces, comma, exclamation marks and etc., all encoded in UTF8.

Using regex with a latin1 string, I could use `preg_replace` and `[a-zA-Z]` to clean it and remove the filler.

How can I keep only the chinese "alphabet" characters in the chinese string while removing all the filler items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this document](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch12.pdf), here are the unicode ranges of chinese characters:

Table 12-2. Blocks Containing Han Ideographs

```
Block                                Range         Comment
CJK Unified Ideographs               4E00–9FFF     Common
CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A   3400–4DBF     Rare
CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B   20000–2A6DF   Rare, historic
CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C   2A700–2B73F   Rare, historic
CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D   2B740–2B81F   Uncommon, some in current use
CJK Compatibility Ideographs         F900–FAFF     Duplicates, unifiable variants, corporate
characters
CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement 2F800–2FA1F Unifiable variants
```

You could use it like this:

```
preg_replace('/[^\u4E00-\u9FFF]+/u', '', $string);
```

or

```
preg_replace('/\P{Han}+/u', '', $string);
```

where `\P` is the negation of `\p`

see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for all the `unicode scripts`

Comment: @David19801: It seems to me you are not using it the correct way. See my edit.

Comment: don't forget to set the /u modifier when you're working with UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope useful for you.

```
str1 = Regex.Replace(str1, @"[\u2E80-\u2FD5\u3190-\u319f\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FCC\uF900-\uFAAD]", "");
```