# Remove Chinese Characters with Preg_replace?

Tags: php

I am trying to remove chinese characters from string. Tried this but can't get this working. It says:

> **Warning:** preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 9 in

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/', '', $string)
```

How can I get this working ?

Comment: Also, use a Unicode [character range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) instead.

Comment: You could filter all *not* latin letters with something like `[^A-Za-z0-9\w\.]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all except the chinese characters with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989133/remove-all-except-the-chinese-characters-with-regex)

Answer (score 10):

> In UTF-8 mode, "\x{...}" is allowed, where the contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits.

You don't appear to be in UTF-8 mode. To enable this mode, add the `u` modifier to the end of the regex.