# Negate multiple character set in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I negate multiple character set in Regex?  The logic is AND, but no such operator available in Regex.

For example:

```js
/[㐀-\u4dbe一-\u9ffe\ud840-\ud868]/g
Hog我新版式打算點sdsd-sad==ds`1wW334/.食。--——‵‶‶‷一、､
```

This pattern matches all Chinese characters, but how I reverse it and exclude all Chinese characters?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989133/remove-all-except-the-chinese-characters-with-regex) answer helps?

Answer (score -1):

The `[㐀-\u4dbe一-\u9ffe\ud840-\ud868]` character class matches some characters and
character ranges you put in the class. The logic in a positive character class is OR.

The negated character class will match any character other than those in the class:

```
[^㐀-\u4dbe一-\u9ffe\ud840-\ud868]
 ^
```

The logic in a negated character class is AND.

Comment: You have two conflicting statements that both start with `The logic in a negated character class is`

Answer (score -2):

Use `^` at the beginning of a `[...]` character class to negate it:

`/[^㐀-\u4dbe一-\u9ffe\ud840-\ud868]/g`

Comment: I tried this but it seems like it is not a perfect solution.  It will miss the character (unlike other character, the length of this one is 2).

I know I can do this too, [^㐀-\u4dbe一-\u9ffe\ud840-\ud868], but I am not sure how many characters with length longer than 1 I would miss.

Comment: ECMAScript standard says: "When a String contains actual textual data, each element is considered to be a single UTF-16 code unit." In other words, if you read an UTF-8 text from a stream or file, and specify as such, it will always be represented as UTF-16 in memory, e.g. 2 bytes per character.